# Problem in installing PDSI package form Github

Tags: r, github, package

Rencently I find a Palmer Drought Severity Index (PDSI) calculation package written by cszang from GIthub. According to the website https://github.com/cszang/pdsi, the install is very easy:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("cszang/pdsi")
```

However, when I install it, an error occurs like this:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : Couldn't resolve host name

Does anyone know about this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is currently down, probably from the DDoS attack currently affecting a bunch of sites including Twitter, Spotify, and more

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @YangYang [You can manually add their IP to your hosts file to get name resolution now.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40184256/4233593)

Comment: @YangYang also seems like GitHub.com is back up now

Comment: @TommyK Yes, it is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `scPDSI` library in R for calculation of Palmer Drought Severity Index.

**Update**

The package has been removed from the CRAN repository. But you can use the following code to install the latest archived version

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/scPDSI/scPDSI_0.1.3.tar.gz", 
                 repo=NULL, type="source")
```