# Trying to clone from github to VM on google cloud compute engine

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, google-compute-engine

Im running a VM instance on google cloud compute engine, trying to clone a repsitory on github onto it i get the folowing:

```
Cloning into 'Up'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyAccount/project.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com`
```

It's running on ubuntu 16.10 and i have checked both the firewall exceptions in the cloud console.

It is worth to note that I was able to clone node.js from github earlier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's due to a DNS outage at Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using any systems that could be affected by the DDoS attack today? Github has been experiencing considerable problems today, and I have also had issues accessing / deploying.

http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/21/major-websites-across-east-coast-knocked-out-in-apparent-ddos-attack.html

I would recommend waiting until later tonight or tomorrow, when GitHub announces everything is back to normal.

https://status.github.com/

Comment: The "Could not resolve host" part of the error strongly suggests this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're desperate for a temporary solution today, like I was, then you can edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add their IP address manually.

```
192.30.253.113  github.com
```

And you will be able to push and pull from repositories. The website is still a little broken from other resources, but it minimally works.